# Why was this question migrated from StackOverflow to here, and can we please revert that?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, migration, specific-question

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/283084/does-cpu-work-like-gpu-when-it-comes-to-prediction-and-if-statements

is clearly formulated in a way that emphasizes what the programming-technical differences between GPU and CPUs are.

It's hence a programming question, and I can't find it covered under the topics in the help center (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

It is especially **not**

> the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications

but it specifically **is**

> Programming software for a PC

So for me, this is clearly off-topic; at the point of asking, at least 11 people seem to [agree](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/283084/does-cpu-work-like-gpu-when-it-comes-to-prediction-and-if-statements/283087#comment645420_283084) with me.

So:

- Why did we accept this migration?
- How to revert it?

---

## edit

Open basically the same question on meta.SO; closing here:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342521/why-was-this-question-migrated-from-stackoverflow-to-ee-se-and-can-we-please-re

Comment: You should really ask that question on SO as they were the ones who initiated it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH agreed; doing that. adding link to there and closing it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should have been asked on meta.stackoverflow.com instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12 people upvoted your comment, but only you have voted to close the question. Nobody has downvoted the question, and it has attracted reasonably high quality answers. Personally I think it's borderline as to being on-topic, so I'm letting the community decide. Comment votes don't count.

To reject a migration, the question simply needs to be closed. That's it.

As to it getting migrated here - that was likely done by a StackOverflow moderator. Migrations are instant, with no way to easily undo it, and no waiting for the destination site to approve. If you disagree with the question being migrated in the first place, then the proper place to complain is meta.SO.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to close it, and it will revert back to the site from which it came.